# Output to JSON & save

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, performance, json

I've got a directory of locations in a channel, 4500 of them.

I'm using the Google Maps addon but given how many locations we're showing, the performance is terrible.

Right now we're outputting the locations via the Query Module to a JS template formatted as JSON. That JSON file is 1.1Mb

What I'd like to do is some how export that to a static JSON file for say 1 day (rather than run the query each time) and see if the performance improves and have it run a cron to update once a day in the background.

Doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but I think [Tag Caching](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/optimization/caching.html#tag-caching) on your query module call does what you're looking for.

I'm sure Stash and CE Cache can be used here, too, if you wrap them around the query module tag.

Comment: Just beat me to it :) Yes, caching should do it. Even 'template caching' should work, depending on your requirements and setup of course.

Comment: We were already using CE Cache but the general use tag didn't seem to have any impact. However, we added the static cache tag to the file and it's blazingly fast now. Thanks.